# Solving $f(x)=f(\frac{1}{x}),\,\,\,x>0$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

What are the non-trivial solutions of the following functional equations: $$f(x)=f(\frac{1}{x}),\,\,\,x>0$$ 
given $f$ if differentiable on $(0,\infty)$.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Do all the solutions attain their absolute max/min at $x=1$?

Comment: One apparent solution is $\left\lvert\ln(x)\right\rvert$.

Comment: One solution is $f(x) = \dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}$.  This holds for $x>0$ and $x<0$.  It also holds for $x=0$ if one regards $1/0$ as the $\infty$ that is neither $+\infty$ nor $-\infty$ but the $\infty$ that is approached by going in either direction, and one takes $f(\infty)$ to be $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.  ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @alex.jordan $|\ln x|$ isn't differentiable at $x = 1$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 OK, then square it, (or take any even positive power of it). So $\left(\ln(x)\right)^2$, $\left(\ln(x)\right)^4$ , etc.

Comment: @OP: The answer to the edit is no, look at alex.jordan's comment above.

Comment: Notice that if $p$ is a symmetric (coefficient-wise) polynomial of degree $m$ that $p(1/x) =(1/x^m)p(x)$. So if $p,q$ are symmetric polynomials of degree $m,n$ then $(p/q)(1/x) = x^{n-m}p(x)/q(x)$. So if $m=n$ and $q(x),q'(x)$ have no positive roots is a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take any even function $g$ with whatever conditions you need (continuous, differentiable, etc.). Then let $f(x)=g\mathopen{}\left(\ln(x)\right)\mathclose{}$.

Comment: This works for @Michael's answer in the comments, with $g(x)=\frac{2\exp(x)}{1+\exp(x)^2}$, which perhaps surprisingly is an even function.

Comment: This is both a necessary and sufficient condition for the original equation. A counterexample for the edited question is thus $\log^4(x)-\log^2(x)$.

Comment: You can prove in general that all functions $f$ have this form, by defining $g(x)=f(e^x)$ and showing that $g$ is even.

Answer (score 3):

Differentiating the functional equation gives

$$
f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2} f'(1/x)
$$

and so, in particular, $f'(1)=0$. So any such $f$ must be of the form
$$
\begin{cases}g(x), & x \in (0, 1] \\
g(1/x), & x \in (1, \infty)\end{cases}
$$
for some differentiable $g$ defined on $(0,1]$ whose left derivative at $1$ vanishes.

Conversely, if $g$ is any such function, then we can define $f$ by the above formula and it will satisfy the functional equation; it will be differentiable at $1$ because the value and derivative of $g(x)$ match up with the value and derivative of $g(1/x)$ there, and it will be differentiable everywhere else by the chain rule.

Comment: Nice solution!  +1